# Don't want to use random generator for game

Tags: c#

The game i am working on has a player that needs to jump and duck under obstacles. I already have it coded in C# to have an random generator. The only thing is, i want to have a sequence of obstacles to spawn that i have in mind. For example, instead of the random, obstacle1, 5, 2, 3, etc. I want obstacle1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and so on, to spawn in the order i would like it to. Not sure on how to start the code for this, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Here is my random example code.

```
private void Creation()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        cObst = Random.Range(0,100);

        if(cObst <= obstL)
        {
            obstacleQueue.Enqueue((Transform) Instantiate(obstHPrefab.transform));
            if(i == 0 && start)
            {
                nextPos = highPos;
            }
        }

        else if(cObst <= obstH && cObst > obstL)
        {
            obstacleQueue.Enqueue((Transform) Instantiate(obstLPrefab.transform));
            if(i == 0 && start)
            {
                nextPos = lowPos;
            }
        }

        else if(cObst <= obstC && cObst > obstH)
        {
            obstacleQueue.Enqueue((Transform) Instantiate(obstCPrefab.transform));
            if(i == 0 && start)
            {
                nextPos =cPos;
            }
        }

        else if(cObst <= obstC && cObst > obstC)
        {
            obstacleQueue.Enqueue((Transform) Instantiate(obstCPrefab.transform));
            if(i == 0 && start)
            {
                nextPos =cPos;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("BREAK");
        }   

    }
}

private void Recycle(float extraZ = 0f)
{
    Transform o = obstacleQueue.Dequeue();
    if(o.name == obstH.name+"(Clone)")
    {
        nextPos = new Vector3(highPos.x,highPos.y,nextPos.z);

    }
    else if(o.name == obstLPrefab.name+"(Clone)")
    {
        nextPos = new Vector3(lowPos.x,lowPos.y,nextPos.z);
    }
    else
    {
        nextPos = new Vector3(carPos.x,carPos.y,nextPos.z);
    }

    nextPos += new Vector3(
        0f,
        0f,
        Random.Range((0-minZ)+extraZ, (0-maxZ)+extraZ));

    Vector3 position = nextPos;
    o.localPosition = position;
    obstacleQueue.Enqueue(o);
}

void Update()
{
    if(curQue <= numberOfObjects && !nextCreate)
    {
        waitCreate = true;
        if(obstacleQueue.Peek().localPosition.z - recycle > char.position.z)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find (obstacleQueue.Peek().name));
            obstacleQueue.Dequeue();
            curQue++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        nextCreate = true;
        StartCoroutine(Wait(0.5f));
        curQue = 1;
    }
}

private void GameStart()
{
    nextPos = transform.localPosition;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        Recycle();
    }

}

IEnumerator Wait(float duration)
{
    if(waitCreate)
    {
        waitCreate = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);   //Wait
        Creation();
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                Recycle(-25f);
            }
            else { Recycle(); }
        }
        nextCreate = false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Area you really unsure how to enumerate then numbers from 1 through 8? I'm unsure what you're asking, and I don't know how the wall of code you've provided is supposed to help.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Can you show in the code where are you having problems with? No one wants to read long chunks of unnecessary code. Tidy up your question please.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Sorry, i am new to this stuff and learning slowly. The code i provided is just my random generator code, sorry thought it could help. What i want is for the obstacles to spawn in a sequence that i have in mind for the level.

Comment: Sorry everyone this is my first time using this site, wasn't too sure what to provide. I am just looking to generate my obstacles in an order i want, not randomly.

Comment: @Aaronmichael There's nothing wrong with being new or being confused! But, you need to be *clear* about what it is you're asking here. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://sscce.org/ - as it stands your question is difficult to understand

Comment: @PrestonGuillot im sorry buddy, ill try and be a little more clearer. As it stands my code generates my obstacles randomly (random generator). What i was looking for was a way to get rid of my random generator, and have my obstacles spawn in an order that i want.

Comment: I'm confused how you can write your random generator code but are incapable of writing code that generates a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign all of the numbers which represent your obstacles in a List. You can just order them sequentially in the List and iterate through one at a time.

```
List<int> Obstacles = new List<int>();
```

Assign them using the following,

```
    Obstacles.Add(1);
    Obstacles.Add(3);
    Obstacles.Add(7);
```

Then you can reference them by replacing,

CObst = Random.Range(0,100);

Use,

CObst = List[i];

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Unity. I think your real problem is not about lists or randomness, but how to spawn objects in order without spawning them all at the same time. The easiest way to do this will be for your spawner script to be a prefab or a scene object, coupled with a Coroutine to delay/prolong execution. The script will have a list of objects. These objects will be set in the inspector.

```
public List<GameObject> objectsToSpawn;
```

Then your spawning logic will spawn one at a time, probably waiting for something in between:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnAll());
}

public IEnumerator SpawnAll()
{
    foreach (GameObject obj in objectsToSpawn)
    {
        GameObject instance = Instantiate(obj) as GameObject;
        // wait for object, see below
    }
}
```

For the delay/wait, you can either use time, or wait for the object to become inactive (if it self-deactivates, like an enemy that will eventually be killed):

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(20);
```

or:

```
while (instance.activeSelf)
    yield return null;
```